# Wither a given FFTW lib was compiled in a single or double precision?

Tags: fftw

Is there a way for to check - wither FFTW was compiled in a single or double precision?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the name of the library is suffixed with an f, it is single precision. Otherwise it is double. E.g.,

libfftw3.a is double-precision

libfftw3f.a is single-precision